# Why is Excel File Opened Exclusively By Another?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I'm creating an SSIS package to loop through a series of Excel files (.xls). I create my while loop container and then create my data flow, which includes an Excel source.

When I edit my Excel source, I create a new connection for my Excel source using a directory where the package is going to use when the package is completed. SSIS is able to load the Excel file into the new connection and preview the columns as well data.

At this point, SSIS can load and read the file. It can access the directory and everything is good to go from this point on.

The next thing I do is create a new package variable that is a string with the value of the same exact path of the Excel connection. Remember, this is the same path that I loaded to create the connection. SSIS can access the directory and read the Excel file.

I then assign the new variable to the Excel connection under the Expression section. I set the Expression property to ExcelFilePath and assign my variable that has the Directory path of the Excel files I want to loop.

After this, I get the error:

> It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need
>   permission to view and write its data.".

What gives? The package is 32-bit and can access the file...

- Excel file is not open.
- I closed/Re-opened Business Intelligence Studio to    ensure it's not opened in
  memory.
- I checked the file permissions, all look good.
- File is not in read only mode.

Comment: I don't suppose you actually have the file open? Or it's on a network drive and someone else has the file open? Just asking because you've not said you haven't...!

Comment: Nope. No file open. I'll update the question to reflect it.

Comment: You might give [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) a try to see what has it. You can filter by file name or path.

Comment: To completely rule out the idea that someone else has the file open. Try making a copy of the file. Then connecting to that copy and see if it works.

Comment: Again, the file is not opened. The file does the same thing local on my computer.

Comment: @Fastidious what does the package look like? Do you have multiple connections to that file within the package?

Comment: The package follows this simple guide to the tee. Keep in mind, I can load the file from the same location as the expression variable. But as soon as I assign the expression variable, it's not accessible -> http://mikedavissql.com/2013/09/16/loop-through-excel-files-in-ssis/

Comment: As a further note, I did the exact same thing with a CSV file and it worked. For some reason, when it comes to looping the Excel document, it fails to open it and gives that warning even though you can remove the variable and directly connect to the file.

Comment: I can [reproduce your error](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2014/10/biml-and-looping-through-excel-files-in.html), if I have Excel open

Comment: I resolved the issue. It seems that the While Loop at the incorrect *.xls* extension verification set. So, it was basically errorring out.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have the right extension and path to the directory set in your variables within each object including the whereloop and connection file.

```
*.xls versus *.xls*
```